# Does the Javascript community have a dependency retrieval (like maven or gem)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maven, rubygems, google-closure

Java has [maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to retrieve dependent jars from various public repositories.

Ruby has even better dependency retrieval tools: gem and bundle.

Does the Javascript community have any equivalent tool? I have found a number of tools to manage dynamically loading dependencies into the browser. I am NOT looking for those tools.

Specifically, I am looking for a tool that a new developer uses to retrieve the javascript files they need. The developer runs this tool and:

1. It looks at the project dependency description file
2. Discovers that the project needs jquery-ui-1.8.7, tiny_mce-3.4.3.2 and prettyLoader-1.0.1
3. Retrieves jquery-ui-1.8.7.min.js, prettyLoader-1.0.1.js, tiny_mce-3.4.3.2 from the web
4. Installs the .js and the .css into a local repository
5. Realizes that jquery-ui relies on jquery-1.6.1 and downloads/installs jquery
6. Determines that the tiny_mce needs the jquery plugin, and downloads and installs it.

After all this, the developer has a local copy of all the js/css files needed.

If a new tiny_mce or jquery comes out, the project file is updated and the developers just return the tool and they get all the new files.

If no version of a js library is specified then the latest release version is retrieved.

---

What I have just described is what maven/ivy/gem does in the java/ruby space.

Obviously, I could rig something up for my own needs with maven but does the javascript community have anything already in place?

Update:

[npm](http://npmjs.org/) was mentioned by Raynos. Npm is centered around node.js ( which is o.k. ). However, there are limited published libraries in the public repository and limited metadata ( version, author, project url is missing from easy discovery ).

However, it looks like npm is the solution today. Unfortunately, it will not quite be enough for us, but such is life.

I am actually pretty surprised that jquery or google-closure does not have a project management tool. (Tell me if I am wrong!)

Update: Now [meteor](http://meteor.com) has come along with meteorite to access and update the atmosphere libraries. Much awesomeness.

Comment: NuGet seems to be Visual Studio tool, not for javascript.

Comment: Yes, but it does Javascript as well.

Comment: Visual Studio means not useful for developers that do not use visual studio. (i.e. people that have Macs and Linux - myself + another dev, or use Windows but have not purchase Visual Studio -everyone else on the team.)

Comment: @Pat Nuget is one of the "tools based on your server-side stack" examples. If your web server is .NET based then you would use NuGet. Also you didn't look hard enough `npm` has many jquery based libraries in their repository

Comment: @Raynos - re: Nuget: being a xplatform developer, I regard anything that is locked to a specific platform as useless. (I should have said that in the original post).

Comment: @Raynos - re: npm : yes you are right thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your server-side stack. Most dependency / package managers for server-side stacks also deal with javascript based dependencies.

[`npm`](http://npmjs.org/) is the node.js dependency manager. It's very popular.

It's based on the CommonJS [package.json](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.0) format.

There are movements to port this to the client like:

- [EnderJS](http://ender.no.de/)

You can't really do this with JavaScript alone as it has no IO in it. Even ender's command line tool relies on npm being installed. You should just use whatever tool comes with your server-side stack

Comment: The client is certainly an important part of the answer. However there needs to be a standardized repository format, standardized packaging format (package.json looks like the js version of java's pom.xml ) and ideally a community-supported repository of packages.

Comment: @Pat yeah the repo is called the [npm repo](http://search.npmjs.org/). _What_ exactly is lacking about npm? If something is lacking get involved with the community and improve it.

Comment: I updated the original question about what was lacking. wrt to "getting involved with the community and improving it". I just did. I listed the specific issues I found by testing npm. My help came in the form of QA/market research.

Comment: @Pat "limited libraries" 6700 is "limited"? "limited metadata", every author uploads his own meta data. Go complain to the authors

Comment: Re:Complaining to authors. See previous comment, there is no ROI in complaining. Either the js community will collectively decide to improve this ... or not. My time is better spent elsewhere. Thanks for letting me know about npm. I will monitor it to see if it & its repository improves for the client-side javascript developer. See mvnrepository.com as an example of what java world uses. thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

it looks like twitter is offering one answer :

cf. https://github.com/twitter/bower#readme

Bower (using Node and npm) is a package manager for the web. Bower lets you easily install assets such as images, CSS and JavaScript, and manages dependencies for you.

Bower is a generic tool which will resolve dependencies and lock packages down to a version. It runs over Git, and is package-agnostic. A package may contain JavaScript, CSS, images, etc., and doesn't rely on any particular transport (AMD, CommonJS, etc.).

Bower then makes available a simple programmatic API which exposes the package dependency model, so that existing build tools (like Sprockets, LoadBuilder, curls.js, Ender, etc.) can consume it and build files accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran across this a few weeks ago. Definitely what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven Javascript Tools project automatically folds in the Maven Javascript Import plugin. The latter plugin brings the world of maven dependency management to JavaScript.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/

Comment: Interesting but no details are on the plugin documentation page about how where the js is pulled from. A major part of maven's value is mvnrepository.com repository.

Comment: The JS is pulled from the same place as other Maven artefacts. By default, this is Maven Central, but other repositories can be added.

Comment: in the middle of dashing around, but I just did a quick search for jquery in mvnrepository.com but nothing listed. So I am not seeing the js code in the mvnrepository.

Answer (score 0):

A new project that combine npm and maven is : https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/introducing-the-npm-maven-plugin/

a very clean integration :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.javascript</groupId>
    <artifactId>npm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>generate-sources</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>fetch-modules</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <packages>
                     <package>colors:0.5.1</package>
                     <package>jshint:0.8.1</package>
                 </packages>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```